# solidity transaction error, The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, remix

I'm learning solidity on remix.
I was following some tutorial video on youtube and I've got stuck trying to build 2 contracts.
contract ERC20Token has function which increases balances. And Mycontract instantiates and call the mint function. I did it the same way as the guy on youtube did, but I ran into error saying when I call buyToken function. The error is saying

> transact to MyContract.buyToken errored: VM error: revert.
>
> revert    The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
>
> Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.    Debug the transaction to get more information.

Please help me out.

Here is the code.

```
pragma solidity 0.5.1;

contract ERC20Token{
   string public name;
   mapping(address => uint256) public balances;

   function mint() public {
       balances[tx.origin] ++;
  }
}

contract MyContract {
   address payable wallet;
   address public token;


   constructor(address payable _wallet, address _token) public {
    wallet = _wallet;
    token = _token;
}

    

   function buyToken() public payable {
       ERC20Token _token = ERC20Token(address(token)); 
       _token.mint();
       wallet.transfer(msg.value);
    
      }
  }
```

[image]

Comment: a bit late this comment, are you sending ether when calling buyToken?

Answer (score 5):

First, you need to deploy the `ERC20Token`.

[image]

In my case, it was deployed to the address `0xcD6a42782d230D7c13A74ddec5dD140e55499Df9`.

[image]

The address of the `ERC20Token` is important for the next step.

---

Then you deploy the `MyContract`. Don't forget to pass the constructor arguments:

- `_wallet` is any valid address in the Remix JS VM emulator (from the `Account` select box)

  For the purpose of this answer, I chose the address `0xCA35b7d915458EF540aDe6068dFe2F44E8fa733c`, that you will see in the third step as well.
- `_token` is the token contract address from the previous step

[image]

---

Finally, you can execute the `buyToken()` function of the `MyContract`.

You can see that before the function execution, the sender has 89 ETH, and is about to send 50 ETH with the transaction.

[image]

After it has been successfully executed, the sender now has 39 ETH, and the `wallet` has received the 50 ETH because of this line:

```
wallet.transfer(msg.value);
```

[image]

And as you can see in the screenshot, the transaction was successful.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You should use payable in your constructor as shown below:

```
constructor(address payable _wallet) public payable{
     ...
}
```

Comment: it is working only in constructor why can't we use in another function

function enter() public payable {
        
}

Answer (score 2):

Because your current balance is 0. You can try to use Low level interactions to send some balance to the contract address.
Let me know if that works!

[image]

Comment: I am having this issue, and this doesn't work. I get the same error when deploying with any amount of wei or ether.

Answer (score 1):

An answer I didn't see anywhere else is the need to just refresh the page/browser if you are running Remix via browser

Answer (score 1):

Check your ENVIRONMENT if you are using remix and make sure you chose Injected web3[for cool guys who using this environment!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9k0F.png)

Answer (score 0):

Check your balance by using balanceOf() function like,
balanceOf(owner). Because, the token you are creating is your balance , if you don't have something you can't buy things. The smart contract that you have write here having the balance as of the no of tokens you own. I'm also have  error in my smart contract too like this and found out this after a day.

To overcome this do the following,

- Add programs to add and subtract balance from the balance of the individual both the buyer and owner.
- If you want give some entry-level balance for new comers to start buy things.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you deploy ERC20Token first. Then next to the deployed ERC20Token is a clipboard to copy the address of the ER20Token. Copy that address into the _token field of MyContract, and copy one of the wallet addresses from the accounts too, into the _wallet field.

Switch account, so you see a different wallet address, and then click the MyContract buyToken button, and you should no longer have an error.

Your code is right, but you are going wrong with wallet/token addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Try going with O wei, since you're using a test environment

Answer (score 0):

This Error also comes when your contract does not have anything to accept ether. Make sure have a look on that. receive() function should exist.

Answer (score 0):

change this line of code : wallet.transfer(msg.value);
to this  wallet.transfer(payable(msg.value));

Comment: Can you add exactly how this solves the issue? - A reference or brief explanation would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who comes here looking for an answer, but the above isn't it, if the function you're calling does not need to receive eth or any value of any sort, i.e the function is not payable and the action to be carried out would be on a front end then Remix can't carry out that function. This was the case for me, but if i'm wrong someone correct me.